# Treat php file as css in Netbeans

Tags: php, css, ide, netbeans-7

So I am working within a PHP framework that puts all of its CSS inside PHP files. In short, the CSS files are called CSS.php even though they do not contain any PHP (just CSS).

I have found that the CSS auto-complete does not like this. Is there anyway to tell netbeans to treat all the code inside these files as CSS without changing the extension?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and have a nice year!

Comment: Your web server will probably serve your css file with the wrong MIME (supposed to be `text/css`), so just change its extension back to `.css`.

Comment: AFAIK there is not any way to do this ...simple trick would be write in css file and than copy past in php file

Comment: can you mention the name of that php framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trick as following:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");?>
```

Also put whatever other files you need to require before beginning of your css code as:

```
<?php require 'config.php';?>
```

Then finally add this line of code which will trick NetBeans to think that you're writing inline css in php file and will work as nothing but a comment line in css file:

```
/*
<style>
/**/
```

Because otherwise if you just add `<style>` to your file if will cause problems when loaded and you will have to put it, work on the file and then remove it, and then recursively put/remove it back whenever you need editing with highlighting and code completion support from NetBeans for the subjected file.

I also highly recommend emmet plugin for NetBeans; a total time saver. I hope this will be helpful for anyone out there.

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans CSS code higlighting and complete in CSS files or inside `<style>` tags.

Not sure is possible use this tags inside CSS files. but you can try this.

And other way is use .css files and in framework use `<?php include("style.css"); ?>` or CSS import directive.